# How can i apply reordering of list in table ion-col in ionic framework

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I want to reorder buttons in the form of rows.
Basically my project is to create a matrix of 12x12 with buttons and each button contains tables value from 1 to 12 for example 12x12=144 button text will be 144. Just like this 144 there 144 buttons in total of each table in the form of rows and columns i want to make them swap-able.

My Front End code is this for reordering.

```
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row reorder="true" (ionItemReorder)="reorderItems($event);">
        <ion-col ion-scroll ion-button *ngFor="let item of listOne">
            {{item}}
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

And TypeScript Code IS

```
    reorderItems(indexes)
       {
           let element=this.listOne[indexes.from];

           this.listOne.splice(indexes.from,11);

           this.listOne.splice(indexes.to,0,element);
        };
    listOne:Array<string>=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12'];
```

Please Help :'( I am stuck in this issue since 2 weeks.

Thank You!
Best Regards.

Comment: so you want to potentially get drag and drop type of experience? the reorder attribute will only work for lists and list items it was specifically tailored for that. You need a drag and drop library to do what you need or maybe custom implementation

Comment: I had tried drag and drop libraries some are old and are not working with new versions and some works but i have to tap first to select item and then tap and press for sometime  to make button movable.. I want that, when i touch button for first time it should stick and when i release touch it should drop there.

Comment: can you add graphically how would you want that to look?

Comment: I'm using https://github.com/timruffles/mobile-drag-drop to enable drag and drop in my Ionic application. Might work for your app aswell...